# Accessing user details from authenticated user in NodeJs using Stytch

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stytch

I am currently working on a web app in NodeJs. I don't want to handle user information in my own database. That's why I've turned to OAuth through the third party library [Stytch](https://stytch.com/).

My implemtation is working as expected in terms of authentication. However, once a user has been successfully authenticated, they are being redirected to a dashboard. Furthermore, a key possibility will be to utilize the users core details (name, e-mail and id).

This seems to only be accessible through the `response` object in scope of the `authentication` method.

I imagine having another separate method and endpoint that can retreive user details. However I don't see how to properly implement this as the data only is accessible in the scope of the `authentication` method upon calling `client.oauth.authenticate(token, options)`.

Below I have provided the route and controller file impacting this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//auth.routes.js
const express = require('express');

const authController = require("./../controllers/auth.controller");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/authenticate", authController.authentication);
router.get("/details", authController.getUserDetails);

module.exports = router;
```

```
//auth.controller.js
const stytch = require('stytch');

const client = new stytch.Client({
    project_id: process.env.STYTCH_PID,
    secret: process.env.STYTCH_SECRET,
    env: process.env.STYTCH_ENV === 'test'
      ? stytch.envs.test
      : stytch.envs.live
  });

exports.authentication = async (req, res) => {
    const { token } = req.query;

    try {
        const response = await client.oauth.authenticate(token, {
            session_management_type: 'stytch',
            session_duration_minutes: 5
        });

        console.log(response);
        const session_token = response.session.stytch_session.session_token;
        res.redirect(`http://localhost:8080?session_token=${session_token}`);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            message: "Authentication Error",
            error: err.message
        });
    }
}

exports.verifyToken = async (req, res) => {
    const { token } = req.body;

    try {
        await client.sessions.authenticate({session_token: token});
        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: "Session Verified"
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            message: "Authentication Error",
            error: err.message
        });
    }
}
```

I have read everything I could get my hands on for consumer authentication in the [Stytch documentation](https://stytch.com/docs). Additionally I've searched all over Google in order to try and resolve this.